# Hooking Python standard library modules

Tags: python, multithreading, import, python-3.x

### Question

I've written a replacement `threading` module for Python. What's the best method to go about hooking all uses of the usual `threading` module from the standard library with my own? The hooking should be opt-in, and on a per project, or per executable basis.

When this statement is executed:

```
import threading
```

I want my module to be loaded instead of the default.

Note that in future, I may also hook several of the other standard modules, so a solution that addresses hooking a few modules is best.

### Why

I've implemented IO concurrency via greenlets and Linux's `eventfd()` and `epoll()` system calls. It works transparently except for a `sys.modules` hook and a replacement `socket` class. Looking to make this hooking nicer and more consistent.

Comment: Just a non-offensive question: Why?

Comment: No, I meant why do you need to replace instead of just having this as another module at `site-packages` ? And why do you want to replace "several" other modules?

Comment: @Matt You're sitting on 12.8k rep and you have not learned how to be polite? Shame on you.

Comment: actually, I think the sys.modules hack may be the best approach

Comment: You've just edited the question from "Replacing Python standard library modules" to "Hooking Python standard library modules". I presume my answer below then isn't what you're after. What exactly is "hooking" in this sense, then? What do you need to happen when you `import threading`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry David, this is one of a string of questions that aren't making sense to anyone.

Comment: @Ben: No, your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using python's meta_path hook:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/

It'll allow you add an object which can override part of the importing process. I think you'll be able to substitute your own modules for the standard modules with that way. I'm not sure its better then patching sys.modules though.

Comment: It seems `sys.modules` is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just put your replacement `threading` module in some directory, and make sure that directory is listed in `PYTHONPATH` when you want to use it? That should mean that directory is searched before the default places when importing `threading`, and Python will find your module and stop.

Comment: Ben, any idea how one could then load the _next_ threading module that would be found if the custom threading module wasn't present?